# JavaFX - How can i start a 24 hour video (using javafx media) at the exact current time from the computer system clock?

Tags: java, javafx, processing

I have a 24hour recording starting at 00:00 hour and ending 24 hours latter. I want to run the program and have it play the video starting at the same time that it is showing on the system clock. For example, it is 20:14 here in Brazil now, so if i execute the program, the video would start playing at the 20hours and 14mins mark.

Basically, i want to sync up the video time with the actual time displayed on the system clock.

My code is kind of messy because the assigment requires the use of Processing ide but for me to actually do what I intend to I'm trying to use Eclipse importing PApplet and all that. Anyway, I just looked up how to play a video using javafx and even though my video is huge it can start playing it instantly.

```
public class UsingProcessing extends PApplet{

  String Dir = System.getProperty("C:");
  Stage stage;

  public static void main(String[] args)  {

      PApplet.main("UsingProcessing");
  }

  public void settings(){

      size(1100, 618,FX2D);
  }

  public void setup(){

      try {

          Field field = PSurfaceFX.class.getDeclaredField("stage");
          field.setAccessible(true);
          stage = (Stage)field.get(surface);

          File f = new File(Dir, "narrativas.mp4");

          Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
          javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer player = new 
          javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
          MediaView viewer = new MediaView(player);

          DoubleProperty width = viewer.fitWidthProperty();
          DoubleProperty height = viewer.fitHeightProperty();
          width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(viewer.sceneProperty(), "width"));
          height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(viewer.sceneProperty(), "height"));
          viewer.setPreserveRatio(true);

          StackPane root = new StackPane();
          root.getChildren().add(viewer);


          Scene scenes = new Scene(root, 1100, 618, Color.BLACK);
          stage.setScene(scenes);
          stage.setTitle("OBSV.CamFeed.6°07'08.3\"S 12°23'51.5\"E");
          stage.setFullScreen(false);
          stage.show();
          player.play();
      } 

      catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

I'm basically using the standard way of playing a video with javafx in Eclipse.

Comment: Sure, if the comment is no longer needed, delete it. And if the complaint in my comment is satisfied, I'll delete my comment as well. The sole purpose of Comments on Stack Overflow is to improve the Question (or Answer).

Comment: Are you aware that days are not always 24-hours long? They can be 23, 25, 23.5, and other numbers of hours long

Comment: i haven't thought about that... In fact i'm not sure i have ever heard about that. Does the computer clock accounts for that variation? I'm thinking that if it does not, the 24hour video can sync up correctly to the system clock time... but i'm not sure now!

Comment: For example sample, in time zone where they practice Daylight Saving Time, in the autumn when they “fall back” an hour, an hour repeats (such as 2 AM), so the day is 25 hours long. Recently, North Korea switched their clock a half hour to match South Korea; while I’m not sure if that was a jump forward or backward, if backward there was a day that was 24.5 hours long. Politicians around the world make these crazy changes to their time zones with surprising frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the duration since midnight:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime startOfDay = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();
java.time.Duration d = java.time.Duration.between(startOfDay, now);
```

Convert that [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) object to a [`javafx.util.Duration`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/util/Duration.html) object.

```
javafx.util.Duration duration = new javafx.util.Duration( d.toMillis() ) ;
```

Then call [`MediaPlayer::setStartTime`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#setStartTime(javafx.util.Duration)).

```
player.setStartTime(duration);
```

Comment: While the specific meaning of the question eludes me, this code looks good. I have one concern: This code implicitly depends on the JVM’s current default time zone. That default can change at any moment during runtime, even between the first and second line of this code. So I suggest always explicitly passing the desired/expected `ZoneId` argument (to `now` & `atStartOfDay`).

Comment: Tip: Try to avoid the terminology of “midnight” as it is ambiguous. "First moment of the day” is precise.

Comment: I would add a caveat about days possibly being longer or shorter than 24 hours.

Comment: **Problem:** Looks like you conflated [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class (and its [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)) method) with the [`javafx.util.Duration`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/util/Duration.html) class to be passed an argument to [`MediaPlayer::seek`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#seek(javafx.util.Duration)).

Comment: I took a stab at correcting the code to convert between `Duration` classes. The `javafx.util.Duration` class constructor actually takes fractions of milliseconds (a `double`), but I assumed whole milliseconds (a `long`) is good enough for the context of this Question.

Comment: It worked perfectly!! Thank you very much. The only change that i did was to use player.setStartTime(duration) instead of player.seek(duration). Now, is it okay for me to edit the answer to include this?

Comment: @94matheus You should have changed the link to the class doc when you changed the method being called. I took care of it now.